# Questioning this closure

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[What should you consider when translating a tube schematic into transistor circuit?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/478243/what-should-you-consider-when-translating-a-tube-schematic-into-transistor-circu)

I got an answer to this question  i dont know why this question was closed.

Whom ever closed this needs to state their case.

Comment: I wasn't involved, but would have voted to close as well if I got to it in time.Their case is pretty clearly stated in the comments.

Answer (score 5):

I didn't vote to close it, but I see it was closed because it "needs more focus."

The problem is, you've asked a general question.  You could write whole books about the subject in your question.  There's really no way to write a satisfactory answer to it.

Specific questions about a particular tube circuit could be answered.  Your general case question just can't really be handled in the format of this site.

The best anyone could do would be to give you what would amount to the table of contents of a book about translating tube circuits to transistors - and even that would be fairly long.

---

As to the answer you got:

People like to help.  Who ever wrote that answer wanted to help.

That "answer" gives you a short bit about one aspect of the conversion - and probably not even the first problem you would run into in real life.

Comment: Interestingly, "People like to help" is the reason we even _have_ Stack Exchange et al. Normal forums drown in crappy answers from everyone who just wants to help.